# Angular - 'ngx-caption' is not a known element in Angular-12 ngx-datatable

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12, I have two modules: AppModule and AdminModule. I am using:

> "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",

for datatable.

**app.module:**

```
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
import {AdminModule} from './features/admin/admin.module';

imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  AdminModule,
  NgxDatatableModule
],
```

**admin.module:**

```
import { AboutUsComponent } from './pages/about-us/about-us.component';
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AboutUsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    NgxDatatableModule
  ]
})
```

AboutUsComponent is inside admin.module:

about-us.component:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about-us',
  templateUrl: './about-us.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about-us.component.scss']
})
export class AboutUsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

```html
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [tableId]="'basic1'" [data]="dataWithCaption" [options]="optionsWithCaption" [columns]="columnsWithCaption">
  <ngx-caption>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-12 ">
        <b>
                  <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Basic Data Table List
                </b>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ngx-caption>
</ngx-datatable>
```

I got this error:

> 'ngx-caption' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'ngx-caption' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'ngx-caption' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to supp

ngx-caption is highlighted.

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

ngx-caption

Comment: Did you check the GitHub repo of @swimlane/ngx-datatable? It does not contain any caption element. Also, there is no npm module that contains ngx-caption. Please mention the link from where you have referred this.

Comment: @DrashtiDobariya - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox%2Fcheckbox.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a module mismatch.

You are using `@swimlane/ngx-datatable`.

While in the stackblitz link that you provided, `@tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable` is used.

Install @tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable - `npm install @tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable`
Then import it into admin module - `import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable';`